# Can anyone explain SSH, SSL, HTTPS in the context of Github or Bitbucket?

Tags: ssl, ssh, https

I don't really know much about IT and have been working in software development for 3 years. I have used version control with Github and Bitbucket, but I really don't know how SSH, SSL, HTTPS works. Can anyone explain them in the context of version control with a cloud service like Github? Why is TLS not used? A user case example would be most helpful. High-level is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, while a number of people think SSH relies on SSL, it doesn't: it's an entirely different protocol. The fact OpenSSH relies on OpenSSL might be one of the causes of this confusion (whereas in fact OpenSSL can do much more than SSL).

Secondly, TLS is essentially a newer version of SSL, and HTTPS is HTTP over SSL/TLS. You can read more about this in ["*What's the difference between SSL, TLS, and HTTPS?*" on Security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/5126/2435), for example.

One of the major differences (in the context of GitHub and Bitbucket) has to do with the authentication mechanisms. Technically, both password and public-key authentication can be used with or on top of SSL/TLS and SSH, but this is done rather differently. Existing libraries and tool support also matters.

GitHub (with Git) relies on an SSH public key for authentication (so that you don't have to store or use a password every time).

Public key authentication in SSH uses "bare keys", whereas you'd need a *certificate* for SSL/TLS (and in 99.9% cases that's going to be an X.509 certificate). (A certificate binds an identity to a public key by signing them together.) GitHub would have to use or set up a CA, or perhaps use various tricks to accept self-signed client certificates. All of this might be technically possible, but this would add to the learning curve (and may also be difficult to implement cleanly, especially if self-signed cert tricks were used).

At the moment, GitHub simply lets you register your SSH public key in your account and uses this for authentication. A number of developers (at least coming from the Git side) would have been familiar with SSH public keys anyway.

Historically, Git over SSH has always worked, whereas support for HTTP came later.

In contrast, Mercurial was mainly an HTTP-based protocol initially. Hence, it was more natural to use what's available on HTTPS (which would rule out using X.509 certificates if they're deemed too complicated). AFAIK, SSH access for Mercurial is also possible.

In both cases (Git and Hg), the SSH public key presented during the connection is what lets the system authenticate the user. On GitHub or Gitlab, you always connect as SSH user `git`, but which key you use is actually what determines the user in the system. (Same with Hg on Bitbucket: `ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/...`.)

Answer (score 1):

I doubt if it is a good question for StackOverflow, however.
All these protocols are used as (secured) channel for Git data exchange. And, when you see 'SSL' most likely SSL/TLS is meant - just to not type both abbreviations. TLS is a further development of SSL protocol.